# mocking elasticsearch in go unit tests

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have the following go code

```
func NewItemAPI(es *elasticsearch.Client, l util.Logger) item.ItemServer {
    return &ItemServerImp{esClient: es, logger: l}
}


func (i *ItemServerImp) Register(ct context.Context, it *item.RegisterItemRequest) (*item.RegisterItemReply, error) {
// doing stuff here
}
```

I'm trying to write unit tests for this.  How do I mock `elasticsearch.Client` At the moment the only thing I can think of is to extract all the methods into an interface and then pass it down, but honestly I don't want to introduce an interface just for this scenario.  Is there a different way I can mock the `elasticsearch.Client`?

Comment: No. To use a mock, you must replace references to the concrete type with references to an interface, and the interface must define any methods you call.

Comment: As @Adrian said, creating an interface is the expected method. It is one of the core parts of golang to move the things you are using out to interfaces, which you can then test. It often produces better code overall, but CAN lead to some somewhat convoluted scenarios. Its normally a good idea to go in with this in mind, as you can better organize everything, and end up with cleaner code overall.

Comment: thanks, I understand why interfaces are a good thing, but in scenarios that I don't want to go down the path of interfaces seems like I have no option.  Is it possible to use something like `mockgen` to generate mocks for the `*elasticsearch.Client`?

Comment: also on the same note, mocking `elasticsearch.Client` should be a common requirement, is there something pre-built out there which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want to test is the response given by the client and handled by `Register`, what you could do instead of mocking the `Client` is mocking the response from Elasticsearch, like this :

```
type mockTransp struct {
    RoundTripFunc func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

func (t *mockTransp) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return t.RoundTripFunc(req)
}

func TestMockClient() {
    c, _ := NewClient(
        Config{
            Transport: &mockTransp{
                RoundTripFunc: func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
                    return &http.Response{Body: io.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("{}"))}, nil
                },
            },
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm looking to actually mock out the whole elastic search client.